# Apply a function based on column name in data.tables R

Tags: r, data.table

I'm looking to apply a user define function based on the name given to a column

```
dt <- data.table(gr_id = 1, id = seq(1,10),min_c = runif(10,10,30),
                 ml_c = runif(10,30,50),mx_c = runif(10,50,100),
                 min_t = runif(10,10,20),ml_t = runif(10,20,25),
                 mx_t = runif(10,25,30))
```

I would like to apply a function which calculates `(min(min)+min(ml))/mx` for both "c" columns and "t" columns. Currently, I've done as follows. However, becomes hard when I want to add more columns (lets say, "a")

```
dt[,{
  temp1 = min(min_c)
  temp2 = min(ml_c)
  temp3 = min(mx_c)
  score_c = (temp1+temp2)/temp3
  temp4 = min(min_t)
  temp5 = min(ml_t)
  temp6 = min(mx_t)
  score_t = (temp4+temp5)/temp6
  list(score_c = score_c,
       score_t = score_t)
},by = gr_id
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work. the basic idea is using `get`.

```
# the original code could be simplified to:
dt[, .(
    score_c = (min(min_c) + min(ml_c)) / min(mx_c),
    score_t = (min(min_t) + min(ml_t)) / min(mx_t)
    ), by = gr_id]
# 
#    gr_id   score_c score_t
# 1:     1 0.9051556 1.28054

# using `get`
cols <- c('c', 't')
dt[, {
    res <- lapply(cols, function(i){
        vars <- paste(c('min', 'ml', 'mx'), i, sep = '_')
        (min(get(vars[1])) + min(get(vars[2]))) / min(get(vars[3]))
    })
    names(res) <- paste('score', cols, sep = '_')
    res
}, by = gr_id]

#    gr_id   score_c score_t
# 1:     1 0.9051556 1.28054
```