# Error with using unlist, lapply and grepl in data.tables R

Tags: r, data.table

This question is an extension of this particular [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40993548/apply-a-function-based-on-column-name-in-data-tables-r). I have this particular data.table. I'm using `data.table`, `mc2d`, and `e1071` libraries

```
library("data.table")
library("mc2d")
library("e1071")
col <- c("COST","TIME")
dt <- structure(
  list(
    ID = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"),COST_PR_L = c(NA, 0.4, 0.31, 0.4, 0.5, 0.17, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5),COST_PR_U = c(7.5, 2, 2.67, 1.67, 2.4,2, 1.5, 2, 2, 1.67),COST_PO_L = c(NA, 0.33, 0.25, 0.44,0.5, 0.25, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5),COST_PO_U = c(3, 1.43, 3.33,1.8, 2.4, 3.6, 1.45, 2, 1.5, 1.67), TIME_PR_L = c(NA, 0.5,0.4, 0.5, 0.5, NA, 0.67, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), TIME_PR_U = c(2,2.5, 3, 1.5, 2, NA, 1.5, 2, 1.67, 2), TIME_PO_L = c(NA,0.4, 0.25, 0.56, 0.5, NA, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), TIME_PO_U = c(2,2, 5, 1.67, 2.5, NA, 1.5, 2, 1.67, 2)
  ),.Names = c("ID","COST_PR_L", "COST_PR_U","COST_PO_L","COST_PO_U","TIME_PR_L","TIME_PR_U","TIME_PO_L","TIME_PO_U"),class = c("data.table","data.frame"),row.names = c(NA,-10L))
```

When I run this particular operation on it,

```
dt[, unlist(lapply(col, function(xx) {
     y = colnames(dt)[grepl(pattern = xx, x = colnames(dt))]
     vars1 = y[grepl(pattern = "PR", x = y)]
     vars2 = y[grepl(pattern = "PO", x = y)]
     mn = get(vars1[1])
     mx = get(vars1[2])
     sk1 = ifelse(mn !=0 && mx !=0,skewness(rpert(1000, min = mn , mode = 1, max= mx )),-1)
     mn = get(vars2[1])
     mx = get(vars2[2])
     sk2 = ifelse(mn !=0 && mx !=0,skewness(rpert(1000, min = mn , mode = 1, max= mx )),-1)
     return(list(sk1, sk2))
 }), recursive = FALSE)
 , by = "ID"]
```

I get the following error

> Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , unlist(lapply(col, function(xx) { :
>   Column 1 of result for group 2 is type 'double' but expecting type
>   'logical'. Column types must be consistent for each group.

However, If I remove the unlist in the code, It seems to calculate the answer. What is unlist doing that is messing it up?

Comment: We don't have `col` so I can't reproduce this, buy I think the error is pretty obvious- you are passing different types to the same column in different `ID`s- but that was already written in the error message... If you keep it a list column, however, R has no problems with it as a `list` column can store different classes.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question with `col`. The code however works when I remove `unlist()`. I was hoping to flatten the results.

Comment: Again, if you remove `unlist`, R has no problem with it because a list can store different classes. In general if you fix your classes, usually `as.list` will flatten the output. BTW, this is still not reproducible as we don't have `skewness`.

Comment: `skewness` is a function part of the `e1071` library as mentioned earlier.

Comment: Your problem is that some values are returned as `NA`s and `NA` is a `logical` in R (by default- see `class(NA)`). Hence, a quick fix (but probably not the most efficient) is to wrap your both `ifelse` statements into `as.numeric`, this way, the `NA`s will be also of class `numeric`. Also, instead of `unlist/lapply` combo, I would just use `sapply`- this way you will also get a flat table as a result

Comment: "When I run this particular operation" -- I doubt we need to see your full code here. You might want to review the typical requirement of questions on this site: [mcve]